# Bootstrap-select & Vue.js: selectpicker('refresh') not working

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-selectpicker

I am trying to implement the bootstrap-select plugin (found here https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/) into a ruby on rails app with Vue.js as the javascript framework.

The objective is that in one select you can pick a category and in the other one you can pick all the teachers available for that category.
To do this i use axios and vue to do a request to my own api and use that to populate the second select and it works fine with a simple select field, however I want bootstrap-select to be shown, I am aware the plugin has a function "selectpicker('refresh')" to make the option reload possible but my browser console claims selectpicker is not a function when I call it on my vue instance, I can manually run it on the browser console however and it works as intended

My code:

js:

```
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
      if(document.getElementById('enrollment_form')) {
      var app = new Vue({
        el: '#enrollment_form',
        data: {
          CategoryValue: null,
          TeacherValue: null,
          teachers: null,
        },
        methods: {
          fetchTeachers() {
            this.axios.get('/api/teachers/' + this.licenceTypeValue).then(response => (this.teachers = response.data))
              $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh');
          }
        }, 
      })
    }})
```

view:

```
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
              <%= f.label :category %>*<br />
              <%= f.collection_select(
                  :category,
                  Category.all,
                  :id,
                  :catgegory_name,
                  {include_blank: true},
                  {
                    class: 'form-control selectpicker',
                    "v-model" => "CategoryValue",
                    "v-on:change" => "fetchTeachers"

                  }
              )%>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-5">
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="teacher_id">Teacher</label>
              <div>
                <select id="teachers-list" class='form-control selectpicker' v-model="TeacherValue" data-fieldname = "TeacherValue">
                  <option label="" ></option>
                  <option v-for="teacher in teachers" :value="teacher.id"> {{teacher.name}}  </option>
                </select>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>  
        </div>

        <div>
          <%= f.hidden_field :teacher_id, {"v-model" => "TeacherValue"} %>
        </div>
```

Finally my application.js

```
//= require rails-ujs
//= require activestorage
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require popper
//= require bootstrap
//= require bootstrap-select
```

I would really appreciate if someone could help as i simply can't figure out what to do

Comment: I was looking at how to use Vue and jQuery together because your question made me curious whether it was possible. Check this out: https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/05/20/vue-js-safely-jquery-plugin/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try changing to the following:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#enrollment_form',
    data: {
        CategoryValue: null,
        TeacherValue: null,
        teachers: null,
    },
    methods: {
        fetchTeachers() {
            // Get the Vue object in a variable so you can use it in the "then" 
            // since 'this' context changes in the "then" handler function.
            let theVue = this;

            this.axios
                .get('/api/teachers/' + this.licenceTypeValue)
                .then(response => {
                    theVue.teachers = response.data;
                    // Call bootstrap-select's 'refresh' using Vue's $nextTick function 
                    // to ensure the update is complete before bootstrap-select is refreshed.
                    theVue.$nextTick(function(){ $('#teachers-list').selectpicker('refresh'); });
                });
        }
    }, 
})
```

I ran into this problem in an application I'm developing, and wrote an article with a more [detailed explanation](https://javascriptjedi.com/vue/solved_vue_with_bootstrap-select.html), including broken and working examples.  My examples change the options via JavaScript without AJAX, but the concept is the same.

In the code above, you are calling the bootstrap-select 'refresh' using Vue's $nextTick function which waits until the Vue object's update is complete before executing the code passed to the $nextTick call.
(see [$nextTick on Vue's documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-nextTick))

*Note: You could also do a more generic update in the Vue's 'update' event handler by adding:*

```
updated: function(){
  this.$nextTick(function(){ $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('refresh'); });
}
```

Please be aware that this will always update all bootstrap-selects that share the same class 'selectpicker'.  The update will occur on every update of the vue data, including those unrelated to the <select>s in question, which is wasteful and could potentially cause performance issues.

I believe the best practice is to refresh just the <select> that needs updating, at the moment it needs the refresh (in your case when the AJAX call returns and the 'teachers' property has been updated.)

Answer (score 0):

If you run it in timeout method, it will be refresh.

```
 setTimeout(function () {
            $(".selectpicker").selectpicker("refresh");
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Hi @Suphi Atlı, welcome to stackoverflow! You're answering an old question which is over 1 year old. Please try to answer new questions, this would be more helpful. And check your answer in the preview before sending it. The code indent is not correct.